# How to run (multiple) dockerized angular apps with nginx inside and nginx as reverse proxy?

Tags: angular, docker, nginx, dockerfile, reverse-proxy

i have the following problem:
i build an angular app with nginx in docker... like this:

```
FROM node:slim as build
WORKDIR /usr/local/app
COPY ./ /usr/local/app/
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build

FROM nginx:latest
COPY --from=build /usr/local/app/dist/myapp /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 4200
```

when i now build and run the dockerfile local... no problem i could enter "localhost:4200" end reach my app.
After that works, i setup github actions and copy my code vis ssh to my vps server.
On this server i have an nginx, which works as reverse proxy.
The nginx config for my angular app looks like that:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {

    listen 443;
    server_name mydomain.com;

    ssl_certificate         /etc/ssl/certs/mydomain.com/cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key     /etc/ssl/certs/mydomain.com/key.pem;

    ssl on;

    access_log            /var/log/nginx/access.log;

    location / {
      proxy_pass          http://0.0.0.0:4200;
    }
  }
```

i create the ssl certificate via cloudflare, and set the tls to strict mode.
Now i thought when i entered mydomain.com -> it goes to my ubuntu server with the installed nginx, checks the certificate and after that it redirects to the docker container, but nothing happens when i try to reach my site, there come a 502 Bad Gateway....

I also tried this nginx config (without cloudflare and ssl) but i also got an 502

```
server {
    listen 80 http2; 
    server_name mydomain.com;
    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:4200;
    }
}
```

Could you maybe help me? I currently not understand why that won´t work.

(i exposed port 4200, and run the angular app like this: `docker run -p 4200:4200 myapp` when i enter `netstat -tulpn` it always says that docker is running under port 4200... but when i make curl on my linux it says:  `(56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to deploy the application as static site. You should not use `ng serve` on production with 4200 port.

Do this

1. Build the application as static site
2. Copy that to NgInx location `/usr/share/nginx/html`
3. Update NgInx to serve from `/usr/share/nginx/html`

Here is the updated NgInx file

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events 
{
     worker_connections 768;
     # multi_accept on;
}

http 
{
    upstream springboot
    {
        server localhost:8080  max_conns=10;
    }

    server
    {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        server_name     <server ip>;

        location /
        {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
        }

    }

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        gzip on;
}
```

Comment: Hello, i deploy it as static site, as you see in the config. But this part with try_files were not in my nginx config. Thx for this :)